# Xamarin Android Designer showing blank page

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Recently I decided to try using Xamarin for developing simple Android applications.

However, I encountered a problem that the Android Designer for layouts either does not work (in latest stable VS 2017) or shows just a blank page (in latest VS 2017 Preview).

Are there any additional steps to set it up or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, Xamarin Designer will not work properly (like the behavior described in my question) if you do not have the correct folder structure. I.e. the layout documents **must** be in the Resources/layout folder, otherwise the Designer will fail.

I already reported this to VS Community and they said that they will have a look at this issue. Hope they will fix it soon.